# Can a `constexpr std::initializer_list` be used at compile time but not ODR-used?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, one-definition-rule

In the following standalone program, I would have expected the `for` loop to be unrolled, or even entirely computed, at compile-time, making `Foo::MyNumbers` unnecessary at link-time:

```
struct Foo
{
  constexpr static auto MyNumbers =
  {
    3,
    28,
    200,
  };
};

constexpr int getSum(void)
{
  auto sum = 0;
  for (constexpr auto i : Foo::MyNumbers)
  {
    sum += i;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

However, even with `-O3`, both `clang++` 3.7 (build from source *prior* to the 3.7 release) and `g++` 5.1 give an similar errors; `clang` says `read of non-constexpr variable '__begin' is not allowed in a constant expression`, while `g++` says `the value of '__for_begin' is not usable in a constant expression`.

I can't really think of anything that could usefully be accomplished at compile-time with a `std::initizlizer_list` without iterating over it, and indeed [the `begin()` method is indeed marked `constexpr` as of C++14](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/begin). So is there anything that can usefully be accomplished with a `constexpr std::initializer_list` that doesn't require ODR-defining it?

**NOTE:** I am compiling with `-std=c++14` on both compilers, but I realize it's possible that they're not fully conformant--even though the versions I'm using are *fairly* recent. I'd be interested to know if more up-to-date versions permit the code above.

**EDIT:** Changed my example and my analysis after discussion with ChrisBeck; see discussion under his answer, as well as edit history for this question.

**EDIT 2:** At T.C.'s suggestion, I removed `constexpr` from the `for` loop, leaving `for (auto i : Foo::MyNumbers)`. This results in an `undefined reference to 'Foo::MyNumbers'` link error with both GCC and Clang.

Comment: Your new example has nothing to do with odr-use and everything to do with the specification of range-based `for`.

Comment: @T.C. Oops. If you're referring to my use of `std::cout` in a `constexpr` function, that was a product of sloppy editing. I've corrected that. As far as I know, as of C++14 , everything in `getSum` should be permissible in a `constexpr` function.

Comment: Nope. You are doing the equivalent of `auto __begin = Foo::MyNumbers.begin(); constexpr auto i = *__begin;`.

Comment: @T.C. ....or are you saying that range-based `for` is *never* allowed in a `constexpr` context?

Comment: IIRC, you cannot access the elements of an array without ODR-using it, and `initializer_list` is based on an array. However, you can do pointer arithmetic on those addresses, e.g. `Foo::MyNumbers.end() - Foo::MyNumbers.begin()`. clang++ refuses to read the elements of the `initializer_list` at compile time, see http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/InGwn1kW94rcuXh0 -- gcc is fine with that.

Answer (score 8):

ODR does not depend on the optimization options. ODR is part of the standard.

The standard does not make reference to optimization options. Instead, different compilers are supposed to make up different optimization schemes as they see fit, and have lots of leeway in that. The ODR is supposed to ensure that conforming code will link on all conforming compilers. (Thank you C++ standards committee!)

So, put it out of your mind about loop unrolling and what that means at link time. The only thing that matters for ODR is whether something is ODR-used.

> I can't really think of anything that could usefully be accomplished at compile-time ... besides loop-unrolling and initializing objects

Since C++14 `std::initializer_list` is a literal type. So, you can easily use it in compile-time computations. Initializing objects that have constexpr constructors using a `std::initializer_list` is very common in some codebases.

Comment: Sorry, but this feels like a non-answer. The mention of `-O3` is because loop-unrolling might not happen without optimization, and without loop-unrolling, the `for` loop would require an actual iterator and the associated run-time baggage, which would require the `std::initializer_list` to exist at runtime--hence it would be ODR-used, so it must be ODR-defined. (And yes, I believe there *are* cases where Clang/GCC will compile code with a high optimization level that fails without optimization).

Comment: When you say "you can easily use it in compile-time computations", you are *looking at an example* of an attempt to use it in a compile-time computation *that failed*. I still don't understand how it can be used. Note that since C++14, `std::initializer_list::begin()` *is* marked `constexpr`.

Comment: Ok, let me say it this way -- loop-unrolling, if it happens, happens AFTER odr is checked. In C++, the ODR must be satisfied WITHOUT assuming that some problematic usage will be eliminated by optimization. Indeed, if you read the standard, you will find that the text of the One Definition Rule makes no reference to loop unrolling, optimizations, dead-code elimination, or any of that.

Comment: If you still feel this is a non-answer, one thing you could do is read the standard, look at your code, try to argue why `Foo::MyNumbers` is not ODR-used, then post a second question marked with "language-lawyer" tag, about why the compiler seems to think that it is ODR-used.

Comment: As for how `constexpr std::initializer_list` could be used, try using it in a `constexpr` function. `int main` is not that. That's really a different question from your question "why doesn't my code link".

Comment: " ... loop-unrolling, if it happens, happens AFTER odr is checked." That cannot possibly be true without LTO. Loop-unrolling would be a compile-time optimization here, and ODR doesn't apply until link time. In addition, I'm *not* breaking the ODR--because I *don't* have more than one definition of `MyNumbers` (I have 0 definitions). And nothing I've said so far should lead you to believe that I expect the standard to talk about optimization or loop-unrolling (!!!!).

Comment: In fact, re-reading my question, I'm not even asking *at all* about ODR violations; I'm just using to qualify what I mean by "use" and "define".

Comment: Ok, I did say something confusing. For the most part, ODR is not checked, it is rather "undefined behavior, no diagnostic required" if you break it. Some problems will generate compile-time errors though. " In addition, I'm not breaking the ODR--because I don't have more than one definition of MyNumbers (I have 0 definitions)." That is not what the ODR says. The ODR says, if a symbol is ODR-used, then it shall have exactly one definition. I believe that you are breaking the ODR, and that that is why you are getting an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109481/discussion-between-kyle-strand-and-chris-beck).

Answer (score 4):

```
for (constexpr auto i : Foo::MyNumbers)
{
  sum += i;
}
```

This is invalid, whether or not the function containing it is `constexpr`, because it expands to

```
{
    auto&& __range = Foo::MyNumbers;
    for(auto __begin = __range.begin(), __end = __range.end();
        __begin != __end;
        ++__begin) {
        constexpr auto i = *__begin;
        sum += i;
    }
}
```

`*__begin` is plainly not a constant expression (it necessitates an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on the non-`constexpr` variable `__begin`), and so cannot be used to initialize the `constexpr` variable `i`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. In that case, why is `begin()` even marked `constexpr`? Can it actually be usefully used in a `constexpr` context?

Comment: @KyleStrand Because you can use that loop in a `constexpr` function just fine if you drop the `constexpr` on `i`?

Comment: I don't think I understand why it matters whether `i` is declared `constexpr` yet, but in fact even removing `constexpr` doesn't fix things; I'm then back to the `undefined reference to 'Foo::MyNumbers'` link-error.